# How do I find common rows and columns in multiple (more than 2) dataframes using pandas?

Tags: pandas

I want to find the `common` rows and columns in all three dataframes: `mrna`, `meth`, and `cna`. I concatenated the three tables by the `Hugo_Symbol`. I'm expecting 343 common columns but am getting 347 common columns.

```
import pandas as pd

from functools import reduce

dfs = [mrna, meth, cna]
common = pd.concat(dfs, join='inner', ignore_index=True)
common = common.drop_duplicates()
common = common.loc[:, ~common.columns.duplicated()]
len(set(common.columns))
```

Current output:

```
347
```

Expected output:

```
343
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need for common columns names use `set.intersection` - ordering should be changed (because in sets is not defined order):

```
out = set.intersection(*map(set,[x.columns for x in dfs]))
```

Or if ordering is important use `reduce` with [`numpy.intersect1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html):

```
out = reduce(np.intersect1d, [x.columns for x in dfs])
```

In your solution common columns should be:

```
common = pd.concat(dfs, join='inner')
out = common.columns.tolist()
out1 = common.index.tolist()
```